# Unable to set psycopg2 autocommit after shp2pgsql import

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I am loading a shapefile into a postGIS database using shp2pgsql, piped via psql, wrapped in a python subprocess like this:

```
command = "shp2pgsql -s 4269 -a -D -W LATIN1 file.shp table | psql -h host -d db -U user"
p=subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

This works perfectly, with the following output:

```
Loading objects...
Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
SET
SET
BEGIN
COMMIT
```

There is no `END` statement, but to the best of my knowledge `END` and `COMMIT` are equivalent.

I then want to set `con.autocommit = True` for a psycopg2 connection to the same database. I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: autocommit cannot be used inside a transaction
```

Why does psycopg2 report that a transaction is still in progress? Is there a different way I should be closing the psql transaction?

If I don't run the shp2pgsql subprocess command, `con.autocommit` executes successfully. Does shp2pgsql by default leave a transaction open somewhere? (http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg doesn't suggest this)

No relevant entries exist in `pg_locks` to suggest a stalled/idle transaction. I do not use the psycopg2 connection object in the shp2pgsql function. And, if I recreate a new connection object

```
con = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_pass, database=db_name)
```

after the shp2pgsql function, `con.autocommit=True` works fine.

Edit: I of course can simply create the psycopg2 connection object after all shp2pgsql imports have finished, but this is not ideal in my code, and I'd rather understand what's happening.

Edit2: setting `con.autocommit=True` immediately after opening the psycopg2 connection, as opposed to later, bypasses this error.

Edit3: adding MWE

```
import psycopg2
import os
import subprocess
from glob import glob

def vacuum(con, table=""):
    autocommit_orig = con.autocommit
    con.autocommit = True
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("VACUUM ANALYZE {};".format(table))
    con.autocommit = autocommit_orig

def read_shapefile(path, tablename, srid="4269"):
    command = "shp2pgsql -s {} -a -D -W LATIN1 {} {} | psql -h {} -d {} -U {}".format(srid, path, tablename, host, dbname, user)
    p=subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    p.communicate()

def load_data(con, datapath):
    dir = os.path.join(datapath,dataname)
    shapefiles = glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.shp"))

    for shapefile in shapefiles:
        read_shapefile(shapefile, tablename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    con = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_pass, database=db_name)
    load_data(con, datapath)
    vacuum(con, tablename)
```

Comment: Could you post an MWE for this? I want to be sure I understand how the code is laid out.

Comment: I've added a MWE above in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see where this is happening, but according to [this](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html), [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4269241), and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/are-transactions-in-postgresql-via-psycopg2-per-cursor-or-per-connection), a transaction is begun the first time a command is sent to the database.

Transactions are per-connection, so `psql` shouldn't be tripping you up.

Following [this advice](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html), my suggestion is that you stick a `con.rollback()` just before `con.autocommit=True` in your code. This will end the implicit transaction that's somehow got started. If you still have all the data you expect, than something's issued a `SELECT` command or similar read-only directive.

If you move the `con.rollback()` backwards from `con.autocommit=True` it will allow you to isolate where the transaction has begun without restructuring your code.

It is a guess, but perhaps when `psql` changes the database state psycopg2 begins a transaction at that time? I haven't found docs to support this hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding some extra info that I discovered when I encountered a similar problem myself just now...

I was trying to do this:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_URL)
conn.autocommit = True
with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("""
    CREATE DATABASE mydb;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
    """)
```

However I kept getting:
`psycopg2.InternalError: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block`

I tried all the various ways:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_URL)
conn.autocommit = True
conn.set_session(autocommit=True)
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

...they all still gave the error.

It turns out the problem was trying to execute two statements at once.

This worked:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_URL)
conn.autocommit = True
with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydb")
    cur.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser")
```